# change vast ads dynamically with media in kaltura

Tags: javascript, kaltura, vast

I'm trying to change media and corresponding vast ads with button clicks in kaltura. I'm using the kdp.setKDPAttribute("configProxy.flashvars.vast","prerollUrl",$(this).attr('preroll')); to set the vast preroll url for the media. Mediafiles I'm using are of url type. I'm adding the setkdpaddtibute in  kWidget.addReadyCallback(function(videoId) where I do the  kdp.sendNotification( "changeMedia", { 'entryId' : $(this).attr('data-entryId') });

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    kWidget.addReadyCallback(function(videoId){
        // add a local ref to the kdp: 
        var kdp = document.getElementById( videoId );
        $( '.changeMedia' ).click(function(){
            kdp.setKDPAttribute("configProxy.flashvars.vast","prerollUrl",$(this).attr('preroll'));
            kdp.sendNotification( "changeMedia", { 'entryId' : $(this).attr('data-entryId') });
            });
        // change media run at the start of the changeMedia sequence
        kdp.kBind('changeMedia', function(data){
            if( data.entryId ){

            $("#changeLog").append( "EntryId: " + data.entryId + "\n");
            }
            })
        // entry ready is run once the entry data has been loaded
        kdp.kBind('entryReady', function(){
            $("#changeLog").append( " Name: " + kdp.evaluate('{mediaProxy.entry.name}') + "\n" );
            })
    });
```

I use the following for the button

I specify the following vast parameters along with the player

```
<script>
  kWidget.embed( 'kaltura_player', {
          'wid' : '_1748561',
          'uiconf_id': '24326282',
          'flashvars': {
              'sourceType':'url',
              'autoPlay': 'true',
              "adsOnReplay" : true,
              "vast": {
              "numPreroll" : "1",
              "skipBtn" : "skip",
              "skipOffset" : "5",
              "prerollStartWith" : "",
              "preSequence" : "1",
              "prerollUrl":"",
              "storeSession" : false,
              "unescapeAdUrls" : false,
              "timeout":"10"
              }
            }
          });
</script>
```

when I load the page, the vast ads donot play. Only the video file plays. Also, kaltura player is sending a http://myserver.com/serverip request to my server. What response does the player expect from the server? 
thanks
phani

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without re-embedding the player, just reload the media. Here's how:

```js
    var entryId = kdp.evaluate('{mediaProxy.entry.id}');
    var prerollUrl = 'your smashingly fancy new url';
    kdp.sendNotification('cleanMedia');
    kdp.setKDPAttribute("vast", "preSequence", 1);
    kdp.setKDPAttribute("vast", "prerollUrl", prerollUrl);
    kdp.sendNotification('changeMedia', {
      'entryId': entryId
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The vast plugin doesnt support dynamic switching of the url.
my suggestion will be to re-embed the player anytime you want to change the url.
kWidget.destroy(..) and then kWidget.embed({..new preroll url..})

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes! I tried re-embedding the player and that works but, each time the player is re-embedded , the user can notice an reload on the screen. thanks again for your reply.